# Looking into getting into Python specifically for a project that involves threads and graphs

Tags: python, c, multithreading, user-interface, graph

I am well experienced in the C languages, but for a project that I have been assigned in one of my classes, I am considering using it as a project to introduce me into Python. I have never used Python before, but I have done some research, and it is very clear that GUI design and Visualizations come very easy to Python; however, I have been unable to find any libraries on threads.

My project is going to have two threads checking an object/class to see if a bool is set so that it can operate on some data and once it's turn is finished it will flag the other thread to operate on that same data. There will be several hundred logged data points on a graph that I will need to display graphically.

**My questions are the following:**

1. Does Python have specific libraries that could help me display graphs with hundreds of points easily? 
         If so, which would you recommend for a beginner in Python?
2. Which thread libraries are best for beginners in Python?

Thank you all for any help in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want threads in Python, as only one can run at a time. Search GIL (here or Google). There are modules like `multiprocessing` that allow easy use of multiple process based concurrency. The following creates two processes that print the strings passed in the args keyword arg. The biggest problem with multiprocessing is that, because it is multiprocess (and the processes have separate address spaces), shared objects have to be handled explicitly.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(name):
  print name

p = mp.Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
q = mp.Process(target=f, args=('jeff',))
p.start()
q.start()
p.join()
q.join()
```

For graphing, see matplotlib. You can use it as a stand alone to just plot and show or you can embed it in a larger GUI library like QT. The following plots a line in matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib as plt

X = [0, 1, 2]
Y = [0, 1, 2]
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

It can also do pretty much any type of graph you can think of (scatter, histo, 3d surf/frame, contour, etc.).

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. In your example, what is the explicit handle for a shared object?

Comment: I didn't include that in the example, b/c nothing was being shared. You can pass objects from one process to another and as long as they don't need to see the changes each other make, no extra work is needed. If they need to see the changes, then you need to share state: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes.

Comment: If you've ever used `mmap` to allocate shared memory for multiprocess apps in C, then it's a lot like that in function but obviously a lot nicer and easier, because it's Python.

Comment: -1 as this explains drawback of threads in Python but says nothing about their handling in Python (which was requested). Moreover GIL problem does not apply in the OP's usecase.

Answer (score 4):

igraph is good for graph visualisation. If you mean plotting points, use matplotlib.

threading module is built-in with python standard library.